# what if I predict data in training dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm developing recommender system using NCF in somewhat modified way.
My circumstance is that data for prediction occasionally includes data used in training.
For example, My training set is 100000rows. And by negative sampling, some unobserved datas are added to training set.
And I want to predict all the unobserved one from the trained model. Then some datas from negative sampling is intersection of train data and predict data.

Will this cause any problem?
Should I remove unobserved data from negative sampling in predict data?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but you should have a separate training and test data . That way you can evaluate your model to determine overfitting or underfitting.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Yes..I know I have to separate training and test data generally. But I doubt very little mixed data still cause any problem.